# Не отображаются созданные процессы посрдеством fork()

Tags: linux, c, syscall

Выполнить программу вывода из файла в файл с помощью функции fork, использую опреденную программу.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    fork();
    system("cd ~/Desktop/2\задание/ && ./cp1_sys file.in file.out");
    return 0;
}
```

Вызвал fork(), далее прошел в директорию , выполнил программу с аргументами.После пишу в терминале ps, а там кроме процессов bash и ps ничего нет... не понимаю...

Comment: Может слишком быстро отрабатывает? И, надеюсь, вы смотрите в процессе выполнения, а не после того, как программа завершилась? Я заменил вызов на `system("sleep 5")` и все отлично работает. `pstree` показывает процессы. Проверял вот такой командой `(./a.out &) && sleep 1 && pstree`

Comment: для таких непоняток следует использовать обработку ошибок при вызове функции

Comment: Следует включать предупреждения в компиляторе. Результат fork не используется, что приводит к фатальным результатам. Собственно и задание не выполняется, так как исполняемый процесс создается посредством `system`. А в строковом литерале неправильная экранирующая последовательность `\з`. По ходу там наверное была попытка сделать экранирующую последовательность для пробела, но в С оно так не делается. Кроме того, следует избегать использования пробелов и кириллицы в путях к файлам, если нет 100% уверенности, что целевая программа рассчитана на работу с ними.